# I want to intall ubuntu alongside window 8

Tags: system-installation

i was trying to install Ubuntu desktop with with window 8 but unfortunately for me i can find my windows anymore which contain a lot of my personnel stuffs almost 1tirabyte. please help me

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still 2013 and we really don't have a crystal ball to see what you did, so please detail what you did before which caused this problem. ☺

Comment: To see all the details you can run Boot-Repair and post the link to the BootInfo report.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can dual boot a system very easily along with your windows operating system. Just follow the steps:
Download Ubuntu

You can download Ubuntu from [ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop.)

Download Unetbootin

Unetbootin is the tool that I used to create a bootable USB drive with Ubuntu on it. To download Unetbootin visit [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/.)

Then after downloading it run Unetbootin
To create a bootable USB drive you need to insert a blank USB drive into a USB port and then select the disk image option.

Clicking on the button with 3 dots brings up a file browser and you should be able to find the downloaded Ubuntu ISO.

Make sure that the USB Drive is indeed in the drive letter specified and when you are happy that you aren't about to install somewhere you shouldn't click OK.

It takes a few minutes for Unetbootin to do it's stuff but ultimately you will end up with a bootable USB drive.
[image: unetbootin]
Turn off fast boot
To turn off fast boot you need to get into the control panel and then the power options.

To open the control panel move your mouse to the top right corner and then click on the settings icon that appears.

When the menu appears click on the control panel.

From within the Control Panel click on the "Power Options" icon.
From the "Power Options" screen look down the menu on the left side and select "Choose what the power button does".On the snappily titled "Define power buttons and turn on password protection" screen scroll down to the bottom.

There should be an option that says "Turn on fast startup". If this option doesn't appear click on the link at the top of the window that says "Change settings that are currently unavailable".

If the "Turn on fast startup" option is checked turn it off. I know that it says recommended but in this case it really isn't recommended.

Click the "Save Changes" button to continue.
Turn off secure boot

To turn off secure boot move your mouse to the top right corner and then click the settings option.

Now comes the ninja bit. Hold down the shift key and select "power" and "restart" whilst keeping the shift key held down. (Take out the USB drive if it is still plugged in).When you reboot a screen similar to the one above will appear. The option you should choose is the UEFI Firmware Settings.

At this point you will be taken into the UEFI settings for your make of computer and I can't write instructions for each make and model therefore Google is your friend (and not at all evil). Type in your make and model and search for UEFI settings.

When you are in the UEFI settings you are looking for the option that says something like "Secure boot" with the value set to "Enabled" and you want to set that option to "disabled".
[image: windows]
Run the Ubuntu Installer
Clicking on the "Install Ubuntu 13.04" (or 12.04 if you are going LTS) brings up the Ubuntu installer.

The first step lets you choose the language for the installer.

If you speak English I recommend choosing English (unless you feel you need an extra challenge) and indeed if you aren't a native English speaker then choose the language you feel most comfortable using.

The preparation screen shows you whether you are fully prepared for installing Ubuntu.

As you can see from the screen image I had plenties of disk space and I was fully plugged in to the power but I didn't have an internet connection.

Having the internet connection set up lets you download updates on the go. I prefer to do it afterwards.

You will also notice the "install this third party software" checkbox which will make Flash and MP3s work straight away after the install.

If you aren't already connected to the internet now is your chance to get connected.

You can choose any one of your broadband connections.

I have 2 available to me and neither of them are any good.

I prefer to install first and update later so  leave the internet disconnected.

Partition the empty space

This bit is going to amend your hard drive partitions and if you didn't do a backup at the beginning this is the point of no return.

I highly recommend making sure you have created the correct recovery media before continuing.

I could have made the install process one big step but the partitioning takes a bit of explaining so I put this in a separate section.[image: ubunut]

There are 2 options available to you from the partitioning screen.
Erase disk and install Ubuntu
Something else
If you just want to install Ubuntu and forget Windows ever existed (and if you have tried Windows 8 nobody is going to blame you for making this decision) you can simply press continue .

This guide is about installing alongside Windows 8 and therefore to do this choose "Something Else"[image]

The disk layout on the Dell Inspiron 3521 is quite involved.

What you should do is look for the large amount of unpartitioned space by scrolling down. (For the Dell it was /dev/sda7).
[image]
When you find the unpartitioned space click on the plus symbol and create a logical partition. Mount the partition to / and set the size to 50 gigabytes. Set the partition type to EXT4.

Now find the unpartitioned space again and click on the plus symbol and create another logical partition. Mount this one to /HOME and set the type to EXT4. The size should be virtually all the unpartitioned space minus about 16 gigabytes.

There is a lot said about how much swap space you need but as disk space isn't exactly expensive anymore I always just choosing 16 gigabytes which is way more than is actually required. (By quite some distance). You will therefore need to create a third partition in the unpartitioned space and choose SWAP as the type.

When it comes to choosing where to install the bootloader don't change a thing. Leave it pointing to "/dev/sda". Whatever you do don't choose one of the other partitions like "/dev/sda1" or "/dev/sda2" etc. This is one of the most common mistakes people make.

For the 3 partitions that you just created make sure the format checkbox is checked.

Do not continue unless you are really satisfied that you have done everything correctly and that you have a backup available in case of bad times.

Press Install to continue.
The installation will now continue and you will see files copied across and the installation taking place.

At this point you will be able to choose keyboard layouts, timezone and you will be asked to add a new user.

At the end of the install process you will asked if you want to restart the system or continue using the live version.

Reboot into the live image

At this point it is worth rebooting the computer to see what has happened.

When the computer has started to reboot remove the USB drive and let the bootup process begin as normal.

If you are lucky everything has worked perfectly well and you have a GRUB menu showing options for Windows and Ubuntu.

The reality is that you will be very lucky if that really has happened.

One of three things will have happened:
Ubuntu will have loaded
Windows will have loaded
Nothing loads
If either Ubuntu or Windows loads then you just have a bootloader issue, if nothing loads it is likely that you didn't turn off secure boot and probably have messages on the screen saying so.

Unless you have a perfectly running dual boot system plug your USB drive back in and reboot so that the live version of Ubuntu runs again.

SOURCE : http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html